# Kivy - FloatLayout alignment problems inside GridLayout Inside ScrollView

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to build a simple app to track my monthly expenses using Kivy and python with data storage via. google firebase. I am having some trouble with a particular screen which I want to list out the expenses for a particular month. Here is the overall nesting of screens and widgets I had to go through in order to get the functionality I wanted.

```
 -> Carousel (to scroll left and right through the different months (created in .KV file))
       -> GridLayout (created in python class)
           -> Label
           -> Scrollview (to scroll up and down through expenses for the month)
               -> gridlayout (because scrollview can only accept 1 widget)
                   -> FloatLayout 
                       -> Image (logo for the particular expense)
                       -> Label (name for the particular expense)
                       -> Label (date of purchase for the particular expense)
                   -> FloatLayout 
                       -> Label (price of particular expense)
```

surprisingly I got it working with one minor caveat, the final 4 widgets (Image, Label, Label, Label) were coming in ALL OVER the place, when ideally I would like an Icon on the left, directly next a label indicating the category of expense, directly under that is the date of purchase, and to the right is the price ([Diagram of screen GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7gMc.jpg)). To help understand what was going on I build a simplified python script to isolate the problem. Since the only portion of my original code in a .KV was the carousel view, I opted to leave that part out for simplicity sake. Here is the simplified version of the code:

'''

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '260')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        SV = ScrollView()
        GL = GridLayout(cols=2, size_hint_y=None, height=self.minimum_height, spacing=(20, 20), row_default_height=40,
                        row_force_default=True)
        GL.bind(minimum_height=GL.setter('height'))
        name = ['PET', 'GROCERIES', 'CLOTHES', 'BOOOOOOOOOOOKS', 'COSMETICS', 'TOILETRIES', 'GAMES']
        numa = ['$ 526.00', '$ 33.00', '$ 1008.28', '$ 10.85', '$ 25.20', '$ 100.00', '$ 66.85']
        x = 0
        for i in range(6):
            # FLOAT LAYOUT FOR PNG, CATEGORY AND DATE
            FL1 = FloatLayout(size=self.size)
            FL1.add_widget(Image(source="pet.png", size_hint=(.4, 1), pos_hint={"right": .4, "y": 0}))
            FL1.add_widget(
                Label(text=name[x], text_size=self.size, size_hint=(1, 1), pos_hint={"x": .35, "y": 1.15},
                      halign='left'))
            FL1.add_widget(
                Label(text='Jan 20', text_size=self.size, size_hint=(1, 0.2), pos_hint={"x": .35, "y": 1.35},
                      halign='left', font_size=10))

            # FLOAT LAYOUT FOR PRICE
            FL3 = FloatLayout()
            FL3.add_widget(
                Label(text=numa[x], text_size=(self.width, None), size_hint=(1, 1), pos_hint={"right": 1, "top": 1},
                      halign='right'))

            # ADD ALL TO GRID
            GL.add_widget(FL1)
            GL.add_widget(FL3)
            x += 1

        SV.add_widget(GL)

        self.add_widget(Button(text='Arbitrary Button 1', background_color=(.7, .5, .9, 1)))
        self.add_widget(SV)
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Arbitrary Button 2', background_color=(.7, .5, .9, 1)))


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


MainApp().run()
```

'''

As you can see if you run this script the widgets are aligning up as I wanted them to, however this was done through using some pretty sketchy coordinates via size_int and pos_hint.

Particularly the the pos_hint "y" propertys are all over the placee

1. Why am i having to set it to 0 in the image and 1.15 in the label to get them aligned to the same top constraint? and 1.35 for the date...
2. How come changing the size hint seems to screw the positioning up sooo badly, and is there a better way to indicate size and position within a gridlayout?
3. lastly, in the third entry where I elongated the work "books" to "boooooooks" for demostration purposes, why is my text wrapping when there is (presumably) still plenty of room to the right for the string to continue on (especially made apparent when maximizing the window...).

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update, I was reworking the code after a fresh nights sleep and was able to pass all the widgets through one floatlayout, and get more accurate pos_hints by first sizing everything accordingly with the size_hint. I am still having an issue with the pos_hint 'y's. I think its something to do with the Image widget. not entirely sure though.

here is the updated code. as well as the PNG image I have been using in case you want to try for yourself. [pet.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoqRT.png)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '260')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')

# size_int (width percentage / height percentage)

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        # Set spacing 2 (1,2) to change the vertical spacing between rows
        SV = ScrollView()
        GL = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None, height=self.minimum_height, spacing=(0, 10), row_default_height=40,
                        row_force_default=True)
        GL.bind(minimum_height=GL.setter('height'))
        name = ['PET', 'GROCERIES', 'CLOTHES', 'BOOOOOOOOOOOKS', 'COSMETICS', 'TOILETRIES', 'GAMES']
        numa = ['$ 526.00', '$ 33.00', '$ 1008.28', '$ 10.85', '$ 25.20', '$ 100.00', '$ 66.85']
        x = 0
        for i in range(6):
            # FLOAT LAYOUT FOR PNG, CATEGORY AND DATE
            FL1 = FloatLayout(size=self.size)
            FL1.add_widget(Image(source="pet.png", size_hint=(.2, 1), pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0}))
            FL1.add_widget(
                Label(text=name[x], text_size=self.size, size_hint=(.5, 1), pos_hint={"x": .125, "y": 1.15},
                      halign='left'))
            FL1.add_widget(
                Label(text='Jan 20', text_size=self.size, size_hint=(.5, 0.2), pos_hint={"x": .125, "y": 1.35},
                      halign='left', font_size=10))
            FL1.add_widget(
                Label(text=numa[x], text_size=(self.width, None), size_hint=(.3, 1), pos_hint={"x": .6, "top": 1.15},
                      halign='right'))
            # FLOAT LAYOUT FOR PRICE
            # FL3 = FloatLayout()


            # ADD ALL TO GRID
            GL.add_widget(FL1)
            # GL.add_widget(FL3)
            x += 1

        SV.add_widget(GL)

        self.add_widget(Button(text='Arbitrary Button 1', background_color=(.7, .5, .9, 1)))
        self.add_widget(SV)
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Arbitrary Button 2', background_color=(.7, .5, .9, 1)))


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


MainApp().run()
```